# Как обновить основную страницу или блок из фрейма?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт на html+css.

В сайте блоки header, navigation, navigation1, content, menu, footer.

В блоке navigation кнопки: Главная, Аккаунт, о сервере, правила, войти.

В блоке navigation1 кнопки: Главная, Аккаунт, о сервере, правила, выйти.

При обращение к сайту проверяю установлены ли куки, и если установлены показываю блок navigation1, если нет, то просто navigation.

```
    function getCookie(name) {
    var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
    var search = " " + name + "=";
    var setStr = null;
    var offset = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if (cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1) {
            offset += search.length;
            end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset)
            if (end == -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }
            setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
    return(setStr);
}

myVar = getCookie("la2user");
if (myVar !== null)
  {document.getElementById("navigation1").style.display = "block";  }
else
  {document.getElementById("navigation").style.display = "block";  }
```

Есть скрипт, который весь код после нажатия кнопок в блоке navigation подгружает в блок content.

```
function changeBlock(id) {
       document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<iframe width="700" height="760" src="http://www.мойсайт.ru/'+id+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
```

Проблема в том, что после того, как я  нажимаю кнопку войти, ввожу логин, пароль, авторизуюсь, меня переправляет на динамическую страницу, которая также грузится в блоке content, с информацией о пользователе, НО блок navigation не меняется на блок navigation1 до тех пор, пока не нажмешь кнопку главная. Пробовал обновлять страницу, но по сути получается что обновляется iframe. Пробовал редиректить со страницы Аккаунт на главную, тогда в iframe загружается еще один iframe (по сути сайт целиком с таким же функционалом). Пробовал в блок контент выводить через jquery, но ситуация такая же, даже еще хуже: все ссылки на странице аккаунт становятся просто текстом. Посоветуйте как мне обновить страницу из фрейма, чтобы отображалась кнопка выйти для авторизованного пользователя?